# confusing mixing datat type in c++

Tags: c++

I am trying to figure out what is happening this code

```
int i = 10, j = 7, l;
unsigned int k;
double q = 3.56;
char c;

c = q * i * j;
l = c;
std::cout << l << "\n"; // result is -7
std::cout << c << "\n"; // result is ?
```

I couldn't understand why l result is '7', and for the c whatever i change the value i, j the result for c is always '?'. Could anyone point me a reason about that ? Thanks

Comment: http://www.asciitable.com/ its a char data type.

Answer (score 6):

The result of `3.56 * 10 * 7` is 249.2.

If the type `char` on your system is a signed 8 bit value with a range from -128 to 127 then attempting to assign 249.2 will cause an overflow. If you assign to an `int` instead of a `char` it will be stored as 249.

The question mark is because -7 is not a printable character.

Comment: Great explanation, except it might be worth adding why "cause an overflow" results in -7 in particular. I'm not sure how to explain it easily without linking to a primer on 2's complement, but "249 - 256 = 7" seems like a start. (And of course C++ doesn't guarantee that signed values work this way, it just happens that the questioner's platform, like most, does it this way.)

Answer (score 1):

The default display method for a char is its ascii/unicode value. For values it cannot display, a ? is shown. 
For others the equivalent character would be shown. For example, a char value of 65 would show `A`

Comment: And as for the -7, see Mark's answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You're writing the value 249.2 into a signed char which is out of the range, so it's converted to the ? character.

Answer (score 0):

3.56*7*10 is 249.200.....2.  It becomes -7 when it is put into a char because a char is an 8 bit signed value.  -7 comes from 249 (truncated) - 256.